# Joda-Time - Number of seconds between two dates

Tags: java, android, unix

My english is not perfect, but I hope you can understand me.

I try to get the difference in seconds between two unix timestamps, but it's only return 0.

That's my code

```
unixOnline = Long.valueOf(online);
unixOffline = Long.valueOf(offline);

DateTimeZone BERLIN = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin");
DateTime dateTimeOnline = new DateTime(unixOnline * 1000L, BERLIN);
DateTime dateTimeOffline = new DateTime(unixOffline * 1000L, BERLIN);

int seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(new LocalDate(dateTimeOnline), new LocalDate(dateTimeOffline)).getSeconds();
System.out.println("Seconds: " + seconds);
```

Edit:
Online Timestamp: 1457536522
Offline Timestamp: 1457536642

Comment: What values of online and offline are you testing with?

Comment: Online Timestamp: 1457536522 Offline Timestamp: 1457536642

Comment: That's 120 seconds difference, which is 0 hours to the nearest hour.

Comment: `int seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(new LocalDate(dateTimeOnline), new LocalDate(dateTimeOffline)).getSeconds();` thats return 0 too

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Yes, second difference in your input is 120, but then you calculate second delta between two `LocalDate`-objects which don't know seconds. Joda-Time handles this situation by implicitly mapping the dates to midnight on same day and sees the same clock time - hence zero second delta.

Comment: Since the `unixOnline` and `unixOffline` values are already in seconds, why not just subtract them? `int seconds = (int)(unixOffline - unixOnline)`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The unix times are in UTC, which means they are absolute times. The code then applies that to `DateTime` in the `Europe/Berlin` timezone, and then converts that to "local" time. On DST switchover, you'll have trouble, e.g. 1:30 CEST - 3:30 CEDT is 1 hour. In unix time, that is 0:30 UTC - 1:30 UTC, and is also 1 hour. In "local" time, it is 1:30 - 3:30, which is 2 hours, even though only 1 hour have passed in real time. By involving "local" time, DST is ignored and you get wrong result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) has no time component, so if the times are on the same day, they're effectively turned into the same time. Instead, just diff the DateTimes as they are;

```
int hours = Hours.hoursBetween(dateTimeOnline, dateTimeOffline).getHours();
```

(or in your case, since the difference is only 2 minutes, you'll only see the result with `Minutes` or `Seconds`)

EDIT: Since the question seems to have nothing to do with the time zone BERLIN which is in the code, this answer is a bit over complicated. Instead, use krzydyn's answer if it's just a time diff between UTC times.

Comment: If the time difference can cross midnight, you should use `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, thanks, definitely a better idea. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have timestamps in seconds it can be simple calculated by formula:

```
 int hours = (t2-t1)/3600;
```

Or if you need fractions:

```
float hours = (t2-t1)/3600f;
```

Update: (maybe I got suggested by the answer :)
So to get time diff in seconds is even simpler:

```
long seconds = t2-t1;
```

Comment: Why give an answer for hours when question is about seconds?

Comment: @Joachim's answer was the solution

Comment: @Andreas Downvoting feels here a little bit too hard because the original question was about hours and not seconds - see edit of OP.

Comment: @CandanTombas Why do you prefer such an awkward solution when the problem is so simple? Seems to be like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut .

Comment: @MenoHochschild Sorry, I didn't see the question until after the edit, and since this answer was done more than 15 minutes after the edit, and after I saw the question, I'd think that answering the updated question would be appropriate. I can't remove down-vote unless answer is updated (down-vote is locked), and I'd be happy to remove it if answer is updated to seconds. I actually suggested that answer in a comment, 10 minutes before this answer was made.